# How to receive optionprices for a certain date wirh Ragtops(R)

Tags: r

My goal is to get the optionprices over a year for the strikedate of 20.05.2020.
I want to do that with the ragtop library. The problem is that if i set the time parameter in the blackscholes-function to 1, it returns the option prices for the strikedate that lies one year in the future for every entry in the series.

```
library(ragtop)
library(quantmod)

volatility = 0.40
tlsa <- (getSymbols("TLSA", source="yahoo", from="2019-01-02", to="2019-12-31", auto.assign=F)[, 4])
bs <- blackscholes(callput=1, S0=price, K=600, r=0.03, time=1, vola=volatility, default_intensity=0)
```

How what can i get option prices over a year for a certain strike date?
Thank you very much guys.